# How to pass datetime input paramter to stored procedure from vb.net application?

Tags: database, vb.net, datetime, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass datetime parameter which is in string format to my stored procedure but its throwing me "String to datetime coversion is not valid" error

Vb. net Code

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Trim(RecordDate),"mm/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@recdate", Asedbtype.DateTime).Value = dt
```

Stored proc

```
Create Procedure sec_edit (
    @recdate datetime
)
```

Please let me know what i should do to avoid this error

Comment: Please post the full exception Stack Trace. What library is `Asedbtype` from?

Comment: Based on your error it is not about the way you send the value to the store procedure ... it is on how you parse your string RecordDate into  DateTime.ParseExtract function. You need to specify also the time format beside date (it is just my assumption)

Comment: Pretty sure this `.Add(@recdate,...` should be this: `.Add("@recdate",...`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error "String to DateTime coversion is not valid", the string could not be formatted into a valid DataTime. The lower case "mm" for the month format should be capitalized: "MM". There are several variants for the date time format, example code below.

```
Dim dateFormat As String() = New String() {"MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy"}
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Trim(RecordDate),dateFormat ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Refer to help documentation for DateTime formats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Dim myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDTP.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",myDateTime)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).